# Problem playing videos with VLC

Tags: arch-linux, vlc

I have installed VLC player in Arch Linux. While playing videos it stutters (the same doesn't happens in Windows for the same videos).

Do I need to install any other package or codecs along with VLC for smooth video playback? I have installed the below packages.

```
pacman -Syu vlc  
pacman -Syu qt4(for GUI)
```

I am using GNOME (don't know if it affects apps).

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problems some time ago and my final solution after some research was to switch to *MPlayer* and its descendents. The original *MPlayer* has just a basic GUI, and I recommend using *SMPlayer* (not perfect but usable) or some other full-featured frontend, depending on your desktop environment.

I wasn't able to configure *VLC* to play certain DVDs smoothly on my system, and it's generally been a resource hog; you can use a CPU monitor to watch the difference. Before I was using *xine*, but it's outdated for quite some time now.

Comment: I specifically picked the MPlayer offshoot *mpv* in this situation